# operator precedence in bison

Tags: substring, bison, tokenize, operator-precedence

I have a flex-bison project in which I need to support a few string operators, and operator '^' means reverse a string and operator [i] means return index i in the string.
correct input and output for example :

```
input : ^"abc"[0]      ---> correct output: "c", my output: "a"
```

that's because first I want to reverse it("cba") and then take the 0 index ("cba"[0] is c).
Now, I don't know how to do that precedence, so my code outputs "a" since it first takes "abc"[0]--> "a" and then reverses it-->"a". as of now I have in my bison file:

```
%left STR MINI
%left '^'         
substring:

STR MINI          {    //THIS IS DONE FIRST, SUBSTRING    
                   $$ = substringFind($1,$2,$2,temp);
                  }
| '^' substring   {   //BUT I WANT THIS (REVERSING) TO BE FIRST    
                  $$ = reverseStrings($2,temp);
                  }
;
```

how do I change that precedence? I don't really understand the precedence rules, it was very easy with plus (+) before multiple (*) but with those operators I don't really know how to work with it.
ANY HELP...?

Comment: You need separate productions, not alternates within the same production. What is MINI?

Comment: MINI is the index, say in "abc"[0] i get mini as 0. I dont understand how to seperate the 2

Comment: @EJP: You could write `substring: STR | substring MINI | '^' substring` along with precedence declarations. The precedence declarations don't work in the OP because there is no conflict to resolve. (Although I prefer the version without precedence declarations, too.)+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need separate productions, not alternates within the same production, something like:

```
string
    : substring
    ;

substring
    : reverse MINI { ... }
    | reverse
    ;

reverse
    : "^" reverse { ... }
    | STR
    ;
```

Comment: I still dont get it, your "reverse" can get only STR, but here I have STR MINI so how would I catch that? when would "reverse" turn into STR ?

Comment: Via `substring: reverse MINI` and `reverse: STR`.